# Xsl find all the node that have then name like the value of an other node

Tags: xml, xslt

How I can find with Xsl  all the node that have then name like the value of an other node
Like these:

```
 <root>
    <data1>
      <subdata1>
        ...
        <selectThese></selectThese>
        ...
      </subdata1>

    </data1>
    <nodesetFind>
      <node1>selectThese</node1>
    </nodesetFind>
  </root>
```

the result: `<selectThese></selectThese>`

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/data1//*[name() = /*/nodesetFind/*]
```

**Demonstrated in an XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/data1//*[name() = /*/nodesetFind/*]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <data1>
      <subdata1>
        ...
        <selectThese></selectThese>
        ...
      </subdata1>

    </data1>
    <nodesetFind>
      <node1>selectThese</node1>
    </nodesetFind>
  </root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<selectThese></selectThese>
```

Comment: @Alejandro, Thanks! You seem to have forgotten the +1? :)

Comment: You are rigth! I must to remember first upvote and then comment... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another way, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kDataByName" match="*[ancestor::data1]" use="name()"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kDataByName',/root/nodesetFind/node1)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<selectThese></selectThese>
```

**Note**: This is XSLT only solution (Dimitre's answer is general XPath, then XSLT) because the use of `fn:key`. So, you need to declare the key for ussing this expression to select the nodes you want:

```
key('kDataByName',/root/nodesetFind/node1)
```

Comment: @Alejandro, When you say "This is XSLT only solution" you mean that this solution cannot work without XSLT, right? At first I thought you meant this solution didn't require XPath. But that didn't make sense.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes. `fn:key` is in scope only for XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="find" select="//nodesetFind/node1" />
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()=$find]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The for-each is unnecessary... you could do `<xsl:copy-of select="//*[name()=$find]" />`. But +1 because useful and correct.

Comment: @LarsH, you're right. I used for-each for some debug printout and forgot to remove it.